# iOS push notification: How does an app get notified about a push notification, when it is in active state?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an application running in the active state. Suddenly I receive a push notification, how does the application get notified about the notification and how does it handle?

Comment: You will get the appdelegate callback. There was some didReceiveRemoteNotification or something like that. I forgot the exact name.

Comment: agreed.  override didReceiveRemoteNotification in the app delegate and then the data will be in userInfo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read about this in apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ModifyingNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH16-SW1).

You need use `didReceiveNotificationRequest:withContentHandler:` in your AppDelegate.

After that you can show notification for user. If you want show notification on active state, you can show alert in application or use system banner.